# How can I transform y (target) data with strings to useable form for artificial neural network using keras?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, transform, target

I'm trying to run an artificial neural network with two layers that categorizes my dataset into one of three categories, based on four independent variables. The target (y) dataset is currently a vector that includes one of three distinct strings, i.e. 'lemon', 'banana', 'orange'. From what I understand, I need to transform the data to an array with a row for each item and three binary columns, indicating either 'yes' or 'no' for each of the three fruits. I'm having difficulty making this happen.

I've tried the using the following function

```
y_data = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_data)
```

but I get an error 
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'lemon'

I've tried making the data categorical and rerunning the function, but the error is the same.

I've also tried making a library and assigning integer values through the library, which I would then run through the above function
    d = {1: 'lemon',2: 'banana', 3: 'orange'}
    y_data = [d[k] for k in y_data]

but I get this error:
   KeyError: 'lemon'
with the error identified at
    y_data = [d[k] for k in y_data]

I've also tried rearranging the strings in the dictionary, and I get the same key error for the same word.

I've also tried making a loop, but again get a key error.

```
X_data = fruit.drop(columns=['Species'],axis=1)
y_data = fruit['Species']
#y_data = y_data.astype('category')
d = {1: "lemon", 2: "banana", 3: 'orange'}
y_data = [d[k] for k in y_data]

y_data = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_data)
```

Comment: Replace each class name with a number. Then `one-hot` encode them using `to_categorical()`

Comment: Thanks! So in order to replace the classes with a number, should I try something other than what I've done already? The only ways I know how to do this is to create a dictionary and ascribe values to each string in the dicitonary. However I get an error when I do this:    d = {1: "lemon", 2: "banana", 3: 'orange'}
y_data = [d[k] for k in y_data];\